# Query Contact using metadata api from soapui or postman

Tags: metadata-api, oauth2, connected-apps

I am working on an assignment where I need to pull specific fields on the contact object with metadata api using Postman or SoapUI.

The metadata api works fine from Salesforce workbench using the below URL.

/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Contact/003xxxxxxxxxxxxx?fields=Id,Name,FirstName,LastName,Title

I did setup a connected app, an integration user in Salesforce. Also, from SoapUI or postman, I am able to get the OAuth access token successfully using the client id, client secret and the credentials of the integration user. However, when I submit a GET request from SoapUI or Postman, I am getting either a "Session Invalid or Expired" or "The requested resource does not exist". The URL that I am using is below.

https://test.salesforce.com/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Contact/003xxxxxxxxxxxxx?fields=Id&access_token=00xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxwrfyQUftcOwmNXMgIecxkX6YiYNW5rcW7mtSG.

If I put the access_token in URL, I get the Session Invalid message. If I put the access token in the auth header, I get the message 'The requested Resource does not exist'.

I have tried several different options, but I am not getting the result that I get in workbench.

Any thoughts?

Comment: silly question, did you give your connected app proper permissions for the object?

Comment: I gave the "manage and access data" permission to the Connected App. The profile of the user has access to contact object.

Comment: I was able to get it working as mentioned in Jayant Das's response. I have created a new profile as "Basic API User" which has the permissions "Call Apex Rest Services", "API Enabled" and "API Only User". The REST API call thru postman is working only if I enable the permission "View All" on the Contact object. I was thinking of re-using the same profile for future requests. So, I created a permission set and enabled the "View All" on Contact object and permission to Connected App. However I get "Requested Resource does not exist" when calling REST API. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you do it.

Few things to note.

- You are trying to hit the REST APIs and not the Metadata API here.
- Make sure you use the instance URL to make the callouts. E.g., if my instance name is say `https://myinstance.my.salesforce.om`, any API callout that I will make will be as `https://myinstance.my.salesforce.om//services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Contact/...`

---

### POSTMAN

1. Use a GET request with the URL
2. Set the Header with key as *Authorization* and value as *Bearer < auth token >*

   Refer to screenshot for details.
   [image]

---

### SOAP UI

1. Create a new REST Project in SOAP UI with your API endpoint
2. Set the Header with key as *Authorization* and value as *Bearer < auth token >*

   Refer to screenshot for details.
   [image]